# Diverging Stacked Barplot in ggplot plotting colors in wrong order

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a diverging stacked bar plot. The expected coloring of the bar plot according the brewer palette should be dark red, light red, white, light blue, then dark blue. But the dark red is getting plotted before the light red.

here is a reproducible example:

```
set.seed(123) 
data <- expand.grid(
  PartyID = c("Democrat", "Republican"),
  response = c("Not at all concerned", "Slightly concerned", 
               "Somewhat concerned", "Very concerned", "Extremely concerned"),
  survey_question = c("Row 1", "Row 2", "Row 3")
)
data$proportion <- pmin(pmax(rnorm(nrow(data), mean = 0.5, sd = 0.2), 0), 1)
data$response <- factor(data$response, levels = c("Not at all concerned",
                                                        "Slightly concerned",
                                                        "Somewhat concerned",
                                                        "Very concerned",
                                                        "Extremely concerned"))
data$proportion <- ifelse(data$response %in% c("Extremely concerned", "Very concerned"), 
                          -abs(data$proportion), 
                          abs(data$proportion)) 
levels(data$response)
# Create the diverging bar plot
ggplot(data, aes(x = survey_question, y = proportion, fill = response)) +
  geom_bar(position = "stack", stat = "identity", width = 0.5) + 
  coord_flip() +
  facet_wrap(~ PartyID, scales = "free") +
  labs(y = "Proportion", x = "Survey Question") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "RdBu", direction = -1) +
  theme_minimal()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the issues which might drive one crazy. A simple fix would be to use a helper column to get the right grouping and order of the stack where you reverse the order of the levels for the bars extending to the left or negative range:

```
library(ggplot2)

data$response_group <- factor(data$response, levels = c(
  "Not at all concerned",
  "Slightly concerned",
  "Somewhat concerned",
  "Extremely concerned",
  "Very concerned"
))

ggplot(data, aes(
  x = survey_question, y = proportion,
  fill = response, group = response_group
)) +
  geom_bar(position = "stack", stat = "identity", width = 0.5) +
  coord_flip() +
  facet_wrap(~PartyID, scales = "free") +
  labs(y = "Proportion", x = "Survey Question") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "RdBu", direction = -1) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]